# Anyway to have google maps display multiple AND unique locations per individual posts/pages?

Tags: google-maps, geo-data

Having the hardest time finding a solution to a big problem. So far I can't find any plugins that are capable of doing this.

I have a site where each post needs to have it's own google map that pulls from a list of locations that are unique to THAT map being displayed on THAT post and displays stores that are around a typed in zip code or address for that sell the displayed item in that post.

The trouble that I'm having is that I can't seem to find any solution that will allow me to have a different map, with a different database of locations entered per post or page. I can only find plugins that allow me to have just ONE central database and then use a shortcode to insert into a post/page.

Where can I find a solution for this? Does it need to be custom developed, if so where do I even start?

Also, my theme is mobile ready it being mobile ready is pretty important. It's highly preferable that whatever solution I use or build work with my mobile ready theme and display correctly in mobile too if possible.